# A Confusing Issue with nextLong() method in java.util.Scanner class

Tags: java, java-7, java.util.scanner

I am trying to run a simple code which will take an account number as the long type from the user through **`nextLong()`** method.Now if the user has given the account_number(`long accNo`) as string_type or character_type instead of long_type value then the **`InputMismatchException`** is thrown.That is also fine,because I am aware of the fact that `nextLong(`) method can throw **`InputMismatchException`** along with **`NoSuchElementException`** and **`IllegalStateException`**.But after that when I am expecting that after getting `InputMismatchException` the loop will revisit and ask me to give the account_number(`long accNo`) as long value again! then the problem occurs.It is not asking me to give any value,instead an infinite loop is running along with the exception again & again.!!

```
 package genericsandcollection;
    import java.util.*;

    public class ScannerTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b=true;
    while(b){
        try{
            System.out.println("Enter Your Account Number..: ");
            long accNo=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(accNo);
            b=false;
            }catch(InputMismatchException | IllegalStateException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
                System.out.println("Wrong syntax");
            }
        }
        }

    }
```

Why is it happening ? Is not `nextLong()` smart enough to handle a situation inside a loop ! If I use `Long.parseLong(sc.next())` instead of `sc.nextLong()`,then everything is alright as `parseLong()` is throwing `NumberFormatException` i.e. until I will give the account number as long_type it keeps asking the user to give the account_number as long_type value.Really Strange !!!! If anybody has any concern,please help.Thank you.

Comment: Why should `nextLong` know to automatically go back to some previous position in the stream based on the surrounding context? (eg: it being in a loop or not)

Comment: put sc.close() inside a finally block...

Comment: @MathiasGhys See my answer. He doesn't WANT it to be closed at all, OR he needs to construct a new scanner at each iteration.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre Yeah but creating new scanner objects is wasteful.

Comment: @all Still problem remains the same,from what point I have asked !

Comment: @Swarn_Ray Have you tried creating a new scanner at each iteration, as suggested in the comments?

Answer (score 3):

Do not close the scanner in the catch block or you won't be able to use it again.

Comment: I have already updated the code according to your concern.But that is not an issue at all..! Even If I completely omit the scanner close part,i.e. sc.close() then also the output is coming as an infinite loop with the exception !!

Comment: @Swarn_Ray According to the code in the OP, you're still closing the Scanner.

Comment: @Radiodef Okk I have removed the Closing of Scanner.Now can you tell me why nextLong() is still unable to take input from 2nd time ????? Falling in Infinite loop is not related to the closing of Scanner I think.

Comment: @Swarn_Ray Have you tried creating a new scanner at each iteration, as suggested in the comments? (copying this comment here just in case)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't close the Scanner because as well as meaning you cannot use the Scanner anymore it will also close `System.in`. Your infinite loop is because using any other method than `nextLine` will leave a line break (from pressing 'enter' to submit) at the end of the input buffer. This will cause nextLong to always throw an exception.

Calling nextLine will advance the Scanner. The following is a short example that shows this (adapted from [a very similar answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20694393/2891664)).

```
do {

    try {
        accNo = sc.nextLong();
        break;

    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    } finally {
        sc.nextLine(); // always advances (even after the break)
    }

    System.out.print("Input must be a number: ");
} while (true);
```