# How to stop exception when type in wrong data type using scanner

Tags: java, exception

Can someone tell me how to prevent this:

`"Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at JeffSky.main(JeffSky.java:25)"`

when the user inputs a letter for an int.

Basically I am trying to find out how to keep the program running even though a wrong data type has been entered. Just like you can do an if statement to notify the user it is not allowed if they input an int outside a given range e.g from 1-10.

for(int x=1; x<=3;x++) {

```
int guess;
        System.out.print("Your chosen trap is: "); 

        do{
            guess=sean.nextInt();

            if(guess>=1 && guess<=6){   
                //do nothing if is a valid number i.e a trap between 1 and 6.
            }                                           
            else {
                System.out.print("Has to be between 1-6. Try again: ");
            }
        }

        while(guess<1 || guess>6);
```

Cheers

Comment: What is `sean`, and where do you initialize it?

Comment: it is a scanner Scanner sean = new Scanner(System.in);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InputMismatchException from nextInt means the input is not an int. [You can catch it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

This will loop until the input is a number between 1 and 6:

```
do {

    try {
        guess = sean.nextInt();

        if (guess >= 1 && guess <= 6) break;

    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    } finally {
        sean.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.print("Input must be a number between 1 and 6: ");
} while (true);
```

Side note: calling nextInt will also orphan a new line character, so nextLine advances past it.

Answer (score 2):

This error is usually thrown when you use methods like `scanner.nextInt();`.  If you want to avoid those, use something like `String input = scanner.next()`, then check `input` to see if it can be represented as an `Integer`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i have this below is there anyway i can do it as int do you know                                              for(int x=1; x<=3;x++) {
   
   int guess;
   System.out.print("Your chosen trap is: "); 
   
   do{
    guess=sean.nextInt();
   
    if(guess>=1 && guess<=6){ 
     //do nothing if is a valid number i.e a trap between 1 and 6.
    }           
    else {
     System.out.print("Has to be between 1-6. Try again: ");
    }
   }
   
   while(guess<1 || guess>6);

Comment: That is exactly what I was talking about.  Change `guess` to a `String`.  Change `scan.nextInt();` to `scan.next();`.  Check to see if `guess` represents an Integer, and if it does, create a new `int` (maybe called guessInt), and store the integer value of `guess` into that new `int`.  (I will let you figure out how do to that, it's a good learning experience).

Comment: If `guess` really is an `int`, then you won't get an `InputMismatchException`.  From [the InputMismatchException API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html): "Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type."

Comment: the second line of the first comment shows as an int idk why the error is showing

Comment: Can you post that code as an edit to your question?  I can't read it in the comment.

Also, please show where you initialize the `Scanner`.

Comment: This will be my final comment on this question - we've cluttered with enough comments already.  `guess` *is an int*.  The issue is, what the user is inputting (via `System.in`), *is not an int*.  As I mentioned before, store the _user input_ into a `String`, check to see if that is an int (there's a method in the `Integer` class to do that), handle any mistakes (print "try again" or something), then store it to `guess`.  Also, it's generally good StackOverflow practice to post the SSCCE (sscce.org) when you first write the question, and then to accept an answer when it's been solved.